# If I'm developing Facebook an app, do I need to apply for a full review to use the page photo upload features in development mode?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm attempting to upload a photo to the a users page using Graph API.  However, I keep getting errors that are related to OAuthException.

This error to be exact : **(#324) Requires upload file**

With such little documentation on the error I'm left dead in the water as a developer in attempting to fix the problem.

Perhaps this is related to the settings?

So,  I'm asking the community :
If I'm developing an app, do I need to apply for a full review to use the upload features during development?
Or
is this simply an tech error that I need to solve ?

Any direction on this matter would be helpful, thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: No, you should not need to get this reviewed, to be able to test it. You are supposed to show them an already _working_ product in app review, and that in most cases would hardly be possible, if people could not test first. (Only thing you need to be aware of, as long as your app is in dev mode, any content created through it will only be visible to people with a role in the app.)

Comment: There are similar questions asked by other developers seeing the same issue. Check these:
* https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17222378/error-requires-upload-file-thrown-in-from-facebook-graph-api
* https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75586693/facebook-page-photo-upload-324-requires-upload-file